# File.OpenRead is too slow

Tags: vb.net, rest

I have an endpoint written in VB.NET and returning a Stream (it allows you to download a zip file). The problem is that when the file is quite large (> 300MB) the "File.OpenRead" instruction takes a few tens of seconds (the file is on the network). Is there anything that allows me to speed up the reading of the file?

```
Private Function DownloadZipFile() As Stream Implements ILUpdateWS.DownloadZipFile
...
   Dim fstream = File.OpenRead(downloadFilePath)
   Return fstream
...
End Function
```

Comment: Instead of using OpenRead try returning just a created file stream ex. Return New FileStream(downloadFilePath, FileMode.Open)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but even so I didn't notice any performance differences.